# Where are PostGis table geometrytype values set?

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

I have a tech stack of Kafka -> Postgres/PostGis -> pg_tileserv -> Varnish cache server. Somewhere along the lines the geometrytype, center, and bounds are being set but I can't figure out where.

"geometrytype": "Point",
"center": [
47.72084999084473,
-12.753128051757812
],
"bounds": [
43.54970169067383,
90,
51.891998291015625,
-115.50625610351562
],

Can this data be set on table creation or modified in any way after creation?

I've looked through all the various PostGis tables created and haven't seen any options.

Comment: Answered my own question. From the pg_tileserv documentation those represent the average/min/max coordinates of the data records. Interestingly those numbers aren't anywhere close to the reality of what is in the database.